# Cast T as having an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

Supposing I have a method:

```
public void DoStuff<T>() where T : IMyInterface {
 ...
}
```

And elsewhere in a different method I want to call

```
public void OtherMethod<T>() where T : class {
...
if (typeof(T) is IMyInterface) // have ascertained that T is IMyInterface
   DoStuff<T>();
}
```

Is there some way I can cast T as having my interface?

`DoStuff<(IMyInterface)T>` and other similar variations wouldn't work for me.

**Edit**: thanks for pointing out that `typeof(T) is IMyInterface` is the wrong way to check for the interface and should instead be called on an actual instance of T.

**Edit2**: I found that `(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` worked in checking for the interface.

Comment: Can't you just call it `DuStuff<IMyInterface>`?

Comment: And another thought: I think that if you need `typeof(T)` within generic method, maybe you shouldn't use generics at all?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I disagree. There are times that you might want to use `typeof(T)` in a generic method. In fact, I'd bet that generics are the most common use of the `typeof` statement.

Comment: `typeof(T) is IMyInterface` is always false. 
But I think you mean `theinstanceOfT is IMyInterface`, right?

Comment: yes I think so, Mikael. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to do that is with reflection. E.g.

```
public void OtherMethod<T>() where T : class {
    if (typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) {
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("DoStuff");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        generic.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeh I was hoping I could avoid that as I am already creating generic methods all over the place! Thanks, though

Comment: @DevDave yeah, IMO it shows shortcomings in C#'s generics support that there's no better way to do this. You can't add a constraint after the fact, you can't have two methods with the same parameters but different type constraints, or anything else to make this easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same syntax to inherit from multiple interfaces:

```
public void OtherMethod<T>() where T : class, IMyInterface {
...
}
```

Comment: This may not be an option (`IMyInterface` may be optional), but if you can do it, this would be my preferred approach.

Comment: thanks, yeah I tried this also. And the problem is that it bubbles up to the calling method. So T as passed from OtherMethod also has to be T : class, IMyInterface and that is not always the case in my code

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
if (typeof(T) is IMyInterface) // have ascertained that T is IMyInterface
   DoStuff<T>();
```

`typeof(T)` returns a `Type`, which will *never* be a `IMyinterface`.  If you have an *instance* of T, you can use

```
if (instanceOfT is IMyInterface) // have ascertained that T is IMyInterface
   DoStuff<T>();
```

or

```
if (instanceOfT is IMyInterface) // have ascertained that T is IMyInterface
   DoStuff<IMyInterface>();
```

Otherwise you could use reflection as [Tim S suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382163/1081897).